# WebServerHost No default VPC for this user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

Im currently trying to launch Cloudwatch and all Alarms from Cloudformation, im using the default template from amazon

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-cloudwatchlogs.html

Im struggeling at this point

```html
 WebServerHost:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      Comment: Install a simple PHP application
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          packages:
            yum:
              httpd: []
              php: []
          files:
            "/tmp/cwlogs/apacheaccess.conf":
              content: !Sub |
                [general]
                state_file= /var/awslogs/agent-state
                [/var/log/httpd/access_log]
                file = /var/log/httpd/access_log
                log_group_name = ${WebServerLogGroup}
                log_stream_name = {instance_id}/apache.log
                datetime_format = %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S
              mode: '000400'
              owner: apache
              group: apache
            "/var/www/html/index.php":
              content: !Sub |
                "<?php"
                "echo '<h1>AWS CloudFormation sample PHP application</h1>';"
                "?>"
              mode: '000644'
              owner: apache
              group: apache
            "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf":
              content: !Sub |
                [main]
                stack= ${AWS::StackId}
                region=${AWS::Region}
              mode: "000400"
              owner: "root"
              group: "root"
            "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf":
              content: !Sub |
                [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
                triggers=post.update
                path=Resources.WebServerHost.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
                action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource WebServerHost --region ${AWS::Region}
              mode: "000400"
              owner: "root"
              group: "root"
          services:
            sysvinit:
              httpd:
                enabled: 'true'
                ensureRunning: 'true'
              sendmail:
                enabled: 'false'
                ensureRunning: 'false'
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT5M
    Properties:
      ImageId:
        Fn::FindInMap:
        - RegionMap
        - Ref: AWS::Region
        - AMI
      KeyName:
        Ref: KeyName
      InstanceType: t1.micro
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref SecurityGroup
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Ref: LogRoleInstanceProfile
      UserData:
        "Fn::Base64":
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
            # Get the latest CloudFormation package
            yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
            # Start cfn-init
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ${AWS::StackId} -r WebServerHost --region ${AWS::Region} || error_exit 'Failed to run cfn-init'
            # Start up the cfn-hup daemon to listen for changes to the EC2 instance metadata
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-hup || error_exit 'Failed to start cfn-hup'
            # Get the CloudWatch Logs agent
            wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py
            # Install the CloudWatch Logs agent
            python awslogs-agent-setup.py -n -r ${AWS::Region} -c /tmp/cwlogs/apacheaccess.conf || error_exit 'Failed to run CloudWatch Logs agent setup'
            # All done so signal success
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource WebServerHost --region ${AWS::Region}
```

when launching the template i get this error

```
    AWS::EC2::Instance  WebServerHost   No default VPC for this user
```

I fixed the problem for the WebServerSecurityGroup when i referenced the VPCId, the thing is the VPCId is not allowed in the WebServerHost properties.

Does someone know how to give a VPC to the WebServerHost ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [SubnetId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-subnetid)

> If you're using Amazon VPC, this property specifies the ID of the
>   subnet that you want to launch the instance into

Comment: doesnt work  AWS::EC2::Instance  WebServerHost  The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.

Comment: I guess, it's because of `InstanceType: t1.micro`, its a previous generation instance type, Can you change it to `t2.micro`?